# How to remove the duplicate list with vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

When adding to the shopping cart, obviously is repeated, i think so it should not be! When I click to the `+`, then go through the list of added shopping carts, This is repeated, I hope this is the list added to the shopping cart should be unique! Go to the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zhouyulong/8ocwtyL0/18/).

#### Look at the gif：

[image]

#### Look at the picture：

[image]

#### javascript:

```js
const phone = [{
      id: "1",
      name: "Iphone 4S",
      price: 300,
      quantity: 0
    }, {
      id: "2",
      name: "Xiaomi",
      price: 200,
      quantity: 0
    }, {
      id: "3",
      name: "vivo X20",
      price: 320,
      quantity: 0
    }]
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    phone:phone,
    addcart: [],
    showcart: false,
  },
  computed: {
    total() {
      var total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < this.addcart.length; i++) {
        total += this.addcart[i].price;
      }
      return total;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    lessClick(item) {
        if (item.quantity > 0) {
          item.quantity -= 1
          const index = this.addcart.indexOf(item)
          if (index > -1) {
            const removedName = this.addcart.splice(index, 1)
            console.log("remove：", removedName)
          }
        }
      },
      addClick(item) {
      this.showcart = false
        item.quantity += 1
        console.log("add：", this.addcart.push(item))

      },
       showCarts(){
       //this.showcart = true      
       }
  }
})
```

#### HTML:

```html
<div id="app">
  <ul class="cart-ul">
    <li v-for="(item,index) in phone">
      Product name： {{item.name}}
      <br>Product price：{{item.price}}
      <br>
      <a class="a-less" @click="lessClick(item)">-</a>
      <input type="text" v-model="item.quantity">
      <a class="a-add" @click="addClick(item)">+</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!--<button @click="showCarts">
     {{addcart.length}}
   </button>-->
  <div class="cart">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="item in addcart">
          <p><strong>{{ item.quantity }}</strong> - {{ item.name }}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
       <h5>Total: <span>{{ total }}</span></h5>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search first if the item is into the list, if it's not, just you add the item, but if the item is into the array just increment the quantity:

```
addClick(item) {
      this.showcart = false;
      const indexItem = this.addcart.findIndex(x=>x.id === item.id);
      if(indexItem >= 0){
        this.addcart[indexItem].quantity += 1;
      }else{
        item.quantity += 1;
        this.addcart.push(item);
      }
},
```